# How to bulk downgrade videos that are higher than 2,000kpbs to be a max of 2,000kpbs with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, plex

I have a problem and that is I want to run Plex on my Raspberry Pi.  It works pretty well. Some of the videos though are too large to stream with the CPU constraints. So in that case I need to make sure the videos are 2,000kbps or less.

I'd like to use FFmpeg to convert all of my mp4s to a lower quality so the Raspberry Pi will not have to do any transcoding.

How could I write a script that would only convert mp4s that have a higher than 2,000kpbs to only be 2,000kbps?

FWIW, this is the command I'm using to convert the videos to have at most a 2000kbps bitrate

```
ffmpeg -b 2000k -minrate 2000k -maxrate 2000k -i "$old_name" -c:v libx264 -tune film -crf 30 -c:a copy "$new_name"
```

This does also make it so plex can stream the videos natively.  Also looks good on a mobile device and good enough for a tv to upstream it.

The question is how do I loop through all of my videos and find all of them that have a bitrate larger than 2000k and run this command?

I found that I can find the bitrate with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "$old_name"
```

But I'd need to extract the value from the output and etc etc.

Comment: Are you sure that the bitrate (2000kb/s) is the main constraint for the CPU load? In my experience it is not, there are much more important factors such as the resolution, the bitdepth, the framerate, the h264 profile and level...  Moreover, on your Plex setup, is the Pi the server or a client?

Comment: Transcoding is not the same thing as the bandwidth of the media stream. Transcoding occurs when a client does not support a given feature of the source media you are playing on it. Plex allows you to pre-transcode media so that when you play it back on a given device no Transcoding is required. Have you tried this? I believe it's called optimized video or something like that.

Comment: What are you streaming **to**? I have a large collection of video files and the only times I have had problems is when the receiving device does not support a high enough "profile" for my media. For example blu-ray disks are often encoded at a profile level of 5.1, but "normal" FireTV sticks only support up to level 4.1 making for bad video playback and transcoding being required. 30Mbps is not a big problem network wise these days, but it depends if your receiver can actually play it. In my case buying one of the "4K" or "Max" sticks was a better solution, no transcoding needed at any point.

Comment: Currently I have been able to get it to stream to my phone now, but for some reason when streaming to a PC I'm getting an error.  "Invalid NAL unit size in extradata" maily just want it to stream to three types of devices, samsung tv, pc, or iphone.